# Is there a way to get the exact Google Sheets page size in inches to use as a size parameter when saving as PDF?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

To generate the PDF, we can use combined inches to produce the page size:

```js
  var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/' +
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' +  //the file ID
      '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +
        '&size=7x6.7' +
          '&portrait=true' +
            '&fitw=true' + 
              '&top_margin=0' +            
                '&bottom_margin=0' +         
                  '&left_margin=0' +        
                    '&right_margin=0' +     
                      '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' +
                        '&pagenum=false' +
                          '&gridlines=false' +
                            '&fzr=FALSE' +
                              '&gid=' +
                                'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //the sheet's ID

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
  var pdfBlob = docurl.getBlob();

  var fileName = 'test';
  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfBlob).setName(fileName);  

  if (DriveApp.getFoldersByName("archives").hasNext()){
    var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("zovo").next();

  } else {
    var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("archives");
  }

  folder.addFile(newFile);
  DriveApp.removeFile(newFile);
```

Specifying the size in:

```
'&size=7x6.7'
```

PDF Result (white background and black cells):
[image]

But if any row or column changes its size, the page already loses its exact size and if it gets bigger it will go beyond the PDF page limit and if it gets smaller it will create an empty margin.

For example:

If any column shrinks in size, this will happen (white background and black cells):
[image]

If any lines decrease in size, this will happen (white background and black cells):
[image]

Is there a way to calc the size of a spreadsheet page in inches to use as a page size parameter to create a PDF?

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wDfi4Iey58MgaUxxXqq6fbIvQ6LAYC9-xgaDgztWt7I/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `If any column shrinks in size` and `If any lines decrease in size` you are thinking. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Of course, for example: currently the exact size I put in the PDF to fit perfectly with the total size of my spreadsheet is ```size=7x6.7```. However, if I decrease the height of the rows and decrease the width of the columns, the size I would have to put would be a smaller one for example something like a ```size=5x4.8```, so to not have to change manually every time, I wanted to know if there is a way to calculate the size of the worksheet automatically.

Comment: And @Tanaike If I could get the width of the columns and the height of the rows, to sum and convert to inches, it would be an option, but I only saw in the documentation ```setRowHeights``` and ```setColumnWidths```, but ```get``` I didn't find.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood `If any column shrinks in size` and `If any lines decrease in size` as `column width is reduced` and `row height is reduced`, respectively. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, in order to confirm your current situation, your sample Spreadsheet for replicating "PDF Result (white background and black cells):" with `&size=7x6.7`?

Comment: @Tanaike Exactly, in general what I meant was that if I change the height or width of columns or rows, automatically the value I put in ```&size=``` will already be wrong, because the current value is specifically for the current sizes.

Comment: In order to confirm your current situation, your sample Spreadsheet for replicating "PDF Result (white background and black cells):" with `&size=7x6.7`?

Comment: @Tanaike I added the example sheet, but I needed to remove the existing data and in the example there is a small white margin at the bottom using ```&size=7x6.7``` because the height of the rows has decreased a little without the data. I'm doing tests to get it out, so far the closest I could get was ```&size=7x6.73622``` but the decimal places need to be bigger to get it right in this specific case.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested it, it seems that the bottom white space is added for various values of the height. For example, even when the height size is reduced and 2 pages are used, the 1st page has the bottom white space. The size of the space can be reduced. But I'm worried that that might not be able to be completely removed. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm afraid it's the fault of the thickness of the borders of the cells, because without changes in the design of the sheet, the white border in PDF doesn't appear.

Comment: Yes. I think so. For example, in my test, when another sheet is used, the size of the bottom white space is different from your sample sheet, even when the calculation method of the height and width is the same. By this, even when an offset is included for adjusting the size, unfortunately, that cannot be used. Because the offset might be different for each sheet. So, I'm worried about the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Script

You can use the script below wherein it computes for the total length and width of the non-empty cells in a Google Spreadsheet.

```
function getsize() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();
  var colWidth = 0;
  for (i=1; i<=lc; i++) {
    colWidth += ss.getColumnWidth(i);
  }
  var width = colWidth / 96;
  console.log("Width = ", width);
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var rowHeight = 0;
  for (i=1; i<=lr; i++) {
    rowHeight += ss.getRowHeight(i);
  }
  var height = rowHeight / 96;
  console.log("Length = ", height)
}
```

The script uses two iterations which sums up the total length and total width of the spreadsheet. This is possible with the use of the `getColumnWidth()` and `getRowHeight()` functions which measure the width and height of the columns and rows, respectively, in pixels.

**NOTE:** The border thickness is not included in the calculation of `getColumnWidth()` and `getRowHeight()`.

### Conversion

After getting the total width and height in pixels, the values are converted into inches by using the proportion:

> 1 inch = 96 pixels

### Sample

I made a test case (10 columns by 9 rows):
[image]

After running the script, I got:
[image]

Upon applying the values to the export link you provided, I got the following as a result:

[image]

### References

You may browse the following references for more information:

- [Comprehensive guide : Export Google Sheets as PDF, Excel, CSV, or other formats using Apps Script](https://spreadsheet.dev/comprehensive-guide-export-google-sheets-to-pdf-excel-csv-apps-script)
- [getColumnWidth()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcolumnwidthcolumnposition)
- [getRowHeight()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrowheightrowposition)

Comment: Hi @PatrickdC Interesting that really in your example, it is perfect without the white border at the end, but in the example sheet that I put in the question, when I try to do it, a white border appears. Is it the format of thickness borders that are causing this problem will be?

Comment: I also tried an all black spreadsheet in my end, all I got was a very thin white space due to the fact that I have rounded up the value I got. When I tried to round down, a portion of the black space was placed on a different page which made more white space in my end. The same thing happened when I thickened the border. I guess border thickness is not counted in the calculation of cell width and height.

Comment: In fact, from what we are analyzing, there is this issue of details regarding borders or changes in the design of the pages, if you want to add these details in the answer, it would be interesting as an additional alert in the case.

Comment: I have added a NOTE to my answer so that other users may be aware of this. Thanks for pointing out the issue with regards to the border thickness.